# Binding Property of an Item in an ItemsControl From a Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

My theory code:

**ScriptContainerUserControl.xaml**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ScriptItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
             <TextBox x:Name="pTB" Text="{Binding PhasePriority}" />
             <TextBox x:Name="nTB" Text="{Binding Name}" />
             <TextBox x:Name="dTB" Text="{Binding Description}" />
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**ScriptContainerUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public ScriptContainerUserControl() : base()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ScriptItemsControl.ItemsSource = PScriptCollection;
}

//PScriptCollecion is of type SynchronizedObservableCollection<ProcessScript>
//ProcessScript has the elements PhasePriority, Name, and Description
```

Would the code above work for making sure

```
 ScriptItemsControl[i].dTB.Text = PScriptCollection[i].Description?
```

Or is it not possible to bind like this?

Comment: You didn't even try it? A hint: Description must be a public property in the element class of PScriptCollection.

Comment: I am trying to fix and issue that is preventing me from testing my theory. Each of the elements are public properties.

Comment: Then it should work. Besides that, you can always write a small test program with exactly what you are showing here. Takes you five minutes.

Comment: @Clemens in your opinion is it better practice to bind the ItemSource Property or does it really matter?

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case, because the source collection is a member of your UserControl and not a property of a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fenster,

It should definitely work, provided you have getter setter properties implemented for all the three properties in ProcessScript class.

When you use a datatemplate - it means you are setting the datacontext of each element of your itemscontrol to an element of your collection.

so here each Itemcontrol element will look at ProcessScript object and if that object has all three properties , you should see the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it in this way. You do not set Binding actually... To have support for observing a changes on collection you should bind the collection to ItemsSource property of ItemsControl.
Instead of line:

```
ScriptItemsControl.ItemsSource = PScriptCollection;
```

try this

```
ScriptItemsControl.ItemsSource = new Binding("PScriptCollection");
```

Comment: Not true. Although it's common to bind the ItemsSource property, it isn't strictly necessary. You can as well make an ordinary assignment.

Comment: Then my idea of trying to bind the items of the Collection to the items of the ItemsControl should work?